# Doctrine persist saving in the database without flush

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am new to Doctrine and having an issue  with the persist & flush
The entity is being automatically saved into the database even if i don't call the flush.
I am using Slim framework for api with Doctrine 2.

```
     public function addSource($request, $response, $args) {
        $apiData = new \App\Entity\Source();
        $apiData->setSourceName('dasds');
        $apiData->setSourceDesc('jasgd<sg');
        $now = new \DateTime("now");
        $apiData->setCreated($now);
        $apiData->setModified($now);
        $this->sourceResource->entityManager->persist($apiData);
        //$this->entityManager->flush();
        echo 'here';exit;
        return $response->withJSON($apiData);
    }
```

In above code, if i put die after the code then It doesn't save into the database but when i let the response sent back, it automatically saves.

Comment: something is odd: $this->sourceResource->entityManager->persist($apiData); //$this->entityManager->flush(); persist() and flush() should be perform from the same em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flush()` is being called elsewhere - probably in middleware or maybe at the end of index.php.

Comment: since there is an explicit exit there is no way flush() can be called after

Comment: @quazardous: Exactly. With the `exit;` the database row is not created. Without the `exit`, it is. I therefore conclude that there is a `flush()` happening after `addSource()` returns…